# Could not add card error when provisioning a card (Apple In-app provisioning)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, applepay, wallet

We encountered an issue while attempting to provision a new card from our app. Specifically, we received a “Could not add card” error message during the process. Here are the steps we took before encountering the error:

- Whitelisted our app and acquired the necessary capability.
- Added the required com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlements.
- Initiated the PKAddPaymentPassViewController with PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration and delegate to begin the provisioning flow.
- Native view is showing to the user with the card details
- User click next
- "Could not add card" error message is showing

Here is how we are initiating the provisioning flow

```
        let config = PKAddPaymentPassRequestConfiguration(encryptionScheme: .ECC_V2)
        config?.cardholderName = "John Doo"
        config?.primaryAccountSuffix = "5432"
        config?.localizedDescription = "brand"

       let vc = PKAddPaymentPassViewController(requestConfiguration: requestConfiguration,   delegate: delegate)
 
        rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        rootVC.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Here is our delegate

```
class PassKitViewControllerDelegate: NSObject, PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate
{

    func addPaymentPassViewController(
        _ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController,
        generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data],
        nonce: Data, nonceSignature: Data,
        completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void)
    {
// This is not triggered when user press next
    }

    func addPaymentPassViewController(
        _ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController,
        didFinishAdding pass: PKPaymentPass?,
        error: Error?)
    {
// This is not triggered when user press next
      }
}
```

However, we did not receive any callbacks to the delegate during the provisioning process, just an error message showing in the screen "Could not add card". We tested our implementation on a device connected to the wallet sandbox environment, using a TestFlight build. We have also reviewed the sysdiagnose and did not find any apparent issues related to this error.